# XLST Translation with White Spaces

Tags: xml, xslt

When creating tags for translation fields in XSLT documents I have a piece of software that can "Auto Map" the fields after the translation of an XML document.

In the XML Document I have a field that reads like this McAfee VirusScan Enterprise 8.8 - Managed

In my XLST I translate that like so.

```
<DCsubject>
    <xsl:value-of select="cdf:Rule/cdf:reference/dc:subject"/>
</DCsubject>
```

The above works fine and there are no issues.

The software I am putting the xml and the xslt into utilize the tag name as the field title.  So the DCsubject tag from the xslt becomes a field called DCsubject.

This same software can automap xslt field name to application field name if I have the tag name the same as the field.  Which would mean I need it to read as "DC subject" <-There is a space between the two.

How could I make a tag have a space in it?If I put a space it errors, if I try to use ASCII (  or similiar) so it would read as a space it errors.

```
<DC subject>
    <xsl:value-of select="cdf:Rule/cdf:reference/dc:subject"/>
</DC subject>
```

Comment: Can you provide any example code illustrating your question?

Comment: I cannot figure out what your question is. Please provide a small example of the input, and the expected output - see: [mcve] -- Note that if you're trying to create an XML element with a name that contains a white space character, that's not going to work. The  XML standard does not allow it.

Comment: The code you added doesn't help a lot yet. Also show us some input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I make a tag have a space in it?

You can't. The name of an XML element cannot contain any white space characters.

Try renaming your fields to say "DC_subject".